# Cordova Android build fail - java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: cordova, gradle, java-runtime-compiler

I am trying to build a Cordova App to test on  my Android device but get the following error:

```
* Where:
Build file 'C:\tm470\karate\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?